# How to make Datatables to look like a Grid?

Tags: javascript, html, datatables-1.10

I'm trying to create a grid with a list of products like below with Datatables.

[image: products]

But only *1 card is shown in each row*. How can i make it look like the grid with *only 3 cards per row*?

[image]

**HTML**

```
<table id="products_table" class="table is-indent tablesaw" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="font-size: medium;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="cell-600" scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="3" style="font-weight: 600;">Product Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
function loadClick() {
  var row = "";
  t.row.add(['<td><div class="demo-card-wide mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp"><div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">' + name +  '</div></div></td>'])
    .node().id = ProductID;

  t.draw(false);
  $("#products_table_processing").css("visibility", "hidden");
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  var table = $('#products_table').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "language": {
      "processing": "<img src='http://i.imgur.com/G6ZMC0N.gif' >"
    }
  });
  $("#products_table_processing").css({ "display": "block", "z-index": 10000 })

  loadClick();
});
```

**Note:**

If it can't be done using datatables. Then please suggest me another way to do this. But i need search & pagination options.

Comment: Well, Cant you use the grid system of CSS to define the 3 columns? and then if there is an over flow, it automatically goes to a new row. Hope this helps.

Comment: Would really love to see a `<table>` with horizontal rows :) What you suggest breaks any meaning with the term "table", and even if you could hack you out with CSS (probably only working in a subset of readers) then it would certainly not work with dataTables. I think you should find a plugin that actually constructs a horizontal grid, seems to be the obvious solution instead of `<table>`'s and dataTables in a way that conflicts with the basic concept of a orderable table.